# How could I parse the return XHR response as a DOM element

Tags: python

I can get the following response by an an POST method request,

The response seems like to show the new added HTML elements by javascript,

I want to parse the new added HTML content, How could I convert the following response into well-formed DOM content for the following parse task.

Thanks

## Response

```
"\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" id=\"hdCurrencySign\" value=\"\r\n          NT$\r\n        \" xmlns:JCode=\"http://www.tiksystems.com/B2C\" xmlns:msxsl=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt\" xmlns:tikLanguage=\"tik:Language\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"YourFlightSelected\" xmlns:JCode=\"http://www.tiksystems.com/B2C\" xmlns:msxsl=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt\" xmlns:tikLanguage=\"tik:Language\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"OutboundFlight\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightType\"\u003e去程航班\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ArrowIconout\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/outbound.png\" class=\"displayimage\" id=\"imgFromImage\" alt=\"\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"YourFlight\"\u003e\u003cul\u003e\u003cli\u003eMM 024\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"YourFlightTime\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"YourFlightTimeDept\"\u003e出發 \r\n\t\t\t\u003cspan\u003e11/24\u003c/span\u003e \r\n\r\n            \u003cspan\u003e10:35\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"YourFlightTimeArri\"\u003e抵達 \r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003cspan\u003e11/24\u003c/span\u003e \r\n\t\t\t\r\n            \u003cspan\u003e14:10\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flightnameleft\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flightname\"\u003eTaipei - Taoyuan\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flightnameright\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flightto\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/to.png\" alt=\"\" title=\"\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flightnameleft\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flightname\"\u003eOsaka - Kansai\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flightnameright\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FareRule\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfare\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfareleftbox\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfaremiddle\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfarerightbox\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfarecontent\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfareheader\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfaretext\"\u003e票價細目\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges\"\u003e\u003cul id=\"ul_Outward_FareInfo\"\u003e\u003cli\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"Taxes_Fees\"\u003e票價\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"collapse\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/expand.png\" alt=\"詳細內容請參照此處\" title=\"詳細內容請參照此處\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges_price_total\"\u003e\r\n          NT$\r\n        4,410\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cul\u003e\u003cli\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges_name\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"amount\"\u003e\r\n                          - 1\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"yourselecttype\"\u003e成人\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges_price\"\u003e\r\n          NT$\r\n        4,410\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges\"\u003e\u003cul id=\"ul_Outward_TaxInfo\"\u003e\u003cli\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"Taxes_Fees\"\u003e稅金、機場稅\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"collapse\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/expand.png\" alt=\"詳細內容請參照此處\" title=\"詳細內容請參照此處\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges_price_total\"\u003e\r\n          NT$\r\n        500\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cul\u003e\u003cli\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges_name\"\u003e\r\n                          - Taiwan Airport Service Tax\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"charges_price\"\u003e\r\n          NT$\r\n        500\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"totalfare fontB\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"totalflight\"\u003e去程合計票價\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv id=\"dv_Outward_TotalInclTax\" class=\"charges_price_total\"\u003e\r\n          NT$\r\n        4,910\u003c/div\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"hdSubTotal\" value=\"4910\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfareleftbottombox\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfaremiddlebottom\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"airfarerightbottombox\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e"%
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi!**

Take a look at [**Beautiful Soup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Also, there's [**xml.dom.minidom**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 0):

How about using `beautifulsoup`?

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(my_response, 'html.parser')
>>> print(soup.prettify())
```